# Voltage scaling of -10 to +10 V analog signal to 0 to 3 V for input to ADC using op-amp

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, operational-amplifier, analog, single-supply-op-amp

I have a sensor which gives an  output of -10 to +10 V. I need to scale down it to 0 to 3V in order to give it as input to the ADC of a microcontroller.

I have the op-amps TL082 and TL431. I have attached a reference circuit as well, but when I simulate, I get a wrong output. Please share your ideas; what do I need to change in the circuit?

Simulation of the model in TINA-TI software:

Vin = 5 V (sine)
Vref= 1.5 V (sine)
Vout= 3.66 V

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the simulation?

Comment: You need to define the correspondence between -10 to +10 and 0 to 3. Do you want -10 to give 0 output, 0 to give 1.5 and +10 to give 3 V?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combined ADC scaling and offset with variable input voltage ranges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22742/combined-adc-scaling-and-offset-with-variable-input-voltage-ranges)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson:  This is a duplicate for sure, though I hope there would be a better example.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the ranges aren't the same

Comment: VREF (VP_5) in your simulation should be 1.5 V**DC**, not 1.5V rms.

Comment: @logee what is your current range?

Comment: is your opamp FAST ENOUGH to provide the desired filtering? You may achieve a cleaner signal, by splitting R7 and R12 into 4 pieces, and using 3 capacitors in a PI configuration to have both differential filtering and common-mode filtering.

Comment: @VoltageSpike:  What we need is a canonical answer that works in terms of "map input I to output range O" in generic terms.  This comes up often, and the questions really only vary in the specifics of the voltages - rarely in real implementation details.

Comment: @voltage spike the current rating would in few mA . not more than 10mA.

Comment: @logee are you sensing forward and reverse current or is it only in one direction?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I saw the reference link but to my understanding it not related to my application.

Comment: @sstobbe I would try Vref with 1.5V VDC

Comment: @VoltageSpike just one direction.

Comment: @sstobbe In Tina simulation software they have either AC analysis or DC analysis, so that i could not check the circuit with Vref 1.5V DC.

Comment: @logee For ac analysis VREF should be 0Vrms and the output will be also be AC only so you won't see the DC offset. You can also simulate your circuit using a DC sweep of Vin from -10 to 10

Answer (score 3):

> I have a sensor which gives an output of -10 to +10 V. I need to scale down it to 0 to 3V in order to give it as input to the ADC of a microcontroller.

The problem requires that

$$V_{out} = \frac{3}{20}(V_{in} + 10\text{ V})$$

which is of the form

$$V_{out} = A_v(V_{in} + V_{offset})$$

Since both \$A_v=\frac{3}{20}\$ and \$V_{offset}=\$ 10 V are positive, we suspect that this transformation may be implementable with a circuit of the form

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMC3eO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ratio between R1 and R2 is given by

$$\frac{R1}{R2} = \frac{V_{offset}}{V_{ref}}$$

Since the TL431 has a nominal voltage of 2.495 V, we will choose that for \$V_{offset}\$, but round it to 2.5 V. This gives us the equation

$$R1 = R2\frac{10}{2.5} = 4R2$$

Because 7.5 k and 30 k are in the ratio of 4:1 and belong to the E24 series of resistors, we will choose them.

The input impedance of the circuit will be the sum of R1 and R2. If need be, we can choose higher valued resistors or use a voltage follower op-amp between the input and the input resistor network here.

What we have so far is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Br1K.png)</sup>

The input resistor network has an attenuates \$V_{in}\$ by a factor of \$\frac{R2}{R1+R2}\$, or \$\frac{1}{5}\$.

So, we need the gain of the remaining circuit to be \$\frac{R1+R2}{R2}A_v = 5 \cdot \frac{3}{20} = \frac{3}{4}\$.

Since this gain is less than 1, and the gain of an op-amp configured as a non-inverting amplifier, and counting the non-inverting input pin as the input, is always greater than or equal to 1, we will shift our topology.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frOhXC.png)</sup>

To calculate the required resistance for R3, we note that
$$R1 || R2 = \frac{(30)(7.5)}{30+7.5} = 6 \text{ k}\Omega$$

To give an additional attenuation of 3/4, the ratio (R1||R2):R3 must be 1:3. So, R3 must be \$\text{18 k}\Omega\$. This gives our final circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4qYfr.png)</sup>

We run a DC sweep, and voila! the circuit performs according to the original spec.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below circuit will convert +/-10V Dc to 0 t0 3.3V. For AC also you can use the same. Change the Vref accordingly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

So you need to do two things for solving your problem.

1. Add a 10V DC offset so the all the voltage goes in a positive direction. you can do that easily using a voltage divider network. I have attached a circuit where I add a 2.5V voltage offset using a voltage divider network(R3 & R4).
2. Now all the volage is range 0-20V. Then use an OP-AMP in a non-inverting amplifier for attenuating the signal to 0-3V. Remember you by doing so you just need a single supply voltage for the op-amp.

[image: Image of how to add voltage offset with dual polarity signal to conver it positive voltage]

Comment: What if the analog signal uses the same reference ground as the rest of the circuit?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson In that case, you have to connect signal and voltage offset together and tie with OP-AMP input. you have to use a dual rail power supply with the op-amp

Comment: @shuvangkar shuvo Thanks for reply. I would try your suggestion in simulation software TI Tina and will post the result.